# Hibernate and spring-orm detect JDBC driver version

Tags: jdbc, spring-jdbc, spring-orm

If I have a JDBC driver that supports JDBC 4.1, and I'm running on JDK 1.8 which has JDBC 4.2, and I use hibernate and spring-orm, are hibernate and spring-orm going to correctly detect the driver version and not use any 4.2 features?

Our current JDBC driver supports JDBC 3.0, and hibernate and spring-orm seem to blindly use it until it tries to hit a method that doesn't exist. Is there a way to force it to use a specific version?

Comment: Having dug through the specs it seems like any driver written against 4.1 will work with 4.2 (thanks to Java 8's default interface implementation feature).